# Vuejs can't refer to array

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I can not reference an array in vue js.

```
  console.log(this.ref_number_response[0]);
```

This show me undefined, and I'm wondering why...

```js
      data(){
        return{ 
           ref_number_response: [],
     }
},
methods:{
check_ref_number: function () {
             // axios request
             axios.get('/is_referenceNumber_free/'+this.ref_number)
             .then(response => this.ref_number_response.push({ 
                 info: response.data

              }));

        
console.log(this.ref_number_response[0]);
           Event.$emit('reference_added', this.ref_number_response);
             
         },
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Ref Number</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input v-model="ref_number" type="text" name="ref_number" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Referent number" @blur="check_ref_number" required>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is the response that i get and I do not want to iterate several times using v-for to get actual diagnosis.

```
[ { "info": [ { "diagnosis": "St. post. trauma testis sin. Obs Ruptura testis sin." }, { "diagnosis": "diagnosi2" } ] } ]
```

Answer (score 4):

It is showing you undefined because the console.log is outside the promise. When you console log it ref_number_response is an empty array and the first element is clearly undefined.

```
data(){
     return { 
           ref_number_response: [],
     };
},
methods: {
   check_ref_number() {
             // axios request
             axios.get('/is_referenceNumber_free/'+this.ref_number)
             .then((response) => {
                  console.log(response.data);
                  this.ref_number_response = response.data;
                  console.log(this.ref_number_response); // now its not empty
                  this.$emit('reference_added', this.ref_number_response);
             });
         },
}
```